# How do I detect the number of keyboards in OSX through command line using bash?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, keyboard

I am trying to write a `bash` script which can detect they number of keyboards currently connected to my MacBook Pro. The keyboards can be the

- default one
- any USB keyboards or
- Bluetooth keyboard

Please give me any suggestions or areas I should be looking for. I am currently using a 2015 MacBook Pro running OSX 10.12.5. I am using the default terminal running bash 4.

Comment: What does "in use" mean (someone typing on it?)... and what have you attempted?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I am looking for number of attached keyboards. Let me go ahead and edit the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I recommend you to try to detect all the usb drivers connected: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device use the script posted on this link and determinate which of these are keyboards. :) good luck. Also this command may help `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`. by: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170105/list-usb-devices-on-osx-command-line

Comment: Thank you @xsasmi. I ended up using this

Answer (score 5):

The `ioreg` command can be used to get a tree of all connected USB devices:

```
ioreg -p IOUSB
```

You can use `sed` to extract just the device names and `grep` to filter out the root nodes from the tree.

```
ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 | sed 's/[^o]*o //; s/@.*$//' | grep -v '^Root.*'
```

Comment: Yes it did in my case. I connected one keyboard through USB and other through Bluetooth to my laptop. Found all 3 keyboards.

Comment: I just tried it here and it returned 10 devices, even though I only have two keyboards (one built-in USB and one Bluetooth). Only one of the 10 devices was a keyboard (the built-in one).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Please add a brief description to your answer and explain what this line of code actually does.

Comment: Edited to add description.